# Smarty Создать приватную зону

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

В smarty есть способ для реализации тега по типу `{admin}{/admin}`. Либо же можно как либо замаскировать `{if $var eq true}{/if}`

Comment: А чем обычный if не устраивает?

Comment: вам видимо сюда https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете добавить свою [блочную функцию](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl).

В контроллере (в пхп коде) вы устаналиваете переменную а-ля

```
$this->_smarty->assign('admin', true);
```

Потом регистрируете плагин

```
$this->_smarty->registerPlugin("block", "admin", function($params, $content, $template, &$repeat){
    if(!$repeat){
        $adm = $template->smarty->getTemplateVars('admin');
        if($adm) {
            return $content;
        }
   }
   return null;
});
```

а в шаблоне используете

```
{admin}hey!{/admin}
```

*По крайней мере можете двигаться в этом направлении и изучать нюансы.*

В такой реализации, конечно, это не отличается от `{if $admin}hey{/if}` но потенциально, можно расширить параметрами и добавить еще какую-то логику, тогда смысл имеет. Например, проверять статус авторизации и роль юзера.

```
{auth allow=['admin', 'editor']}hey!{/auth}
```

проверяя внутри не только `user` но и сравнивая условный `$user->role` с `$params['allow']`

Comment: Teran блок был приведён в пример. Хотел сделать приватные зоны для конкретных ролей

Comment: @old. если сей ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос, то ткните галку